# (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open existing database file in a new session?

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, sqlalchemy

In my project I use context manager with thread lock:

```
@contextmanager                                                                                                                                                                       
def session_context(base):
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    base.lock.acquire()
    new_session = base.Session()
    try:
        yield new_session
        new_session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        if hasattr(e, "code"):
            base.log.error(f'Error: {e.code}')
        if hasattr(base, 'log'):
            base.log.error(f'DB error:\n{type(e)} \n{e}')
        new_session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        new_session.close()
        if base.lock.locked():
            base.lock.release()


class BaseDB:

    def __init__(self, db_path, name):
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.db_path = db_path
        self.Session = self.create_connection(base=Base, class_name=name)                                 

    def create_connection(self, base, class_name='SbDatabase', table_objects=None, execution_options=None, echo=False):
        engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{self.db_path}{class_name}.sqlite',
                               connect_args={'check_same_thread': False, 'timeout': 20},
                               execution_options=execution_options,
                               echo=echo)
        engine.execute('PRAGMA encoding="UTF-8"')
        session_creator = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False)
        base.metadata.create_all(engine, tables=table_objects)
        # return scoped_session(session_creator)
        return session_creator

    def add_task(self, **kwargs):
        with session_context(self) as session:
            task = PluginTask(**kwargs)
            session.add(task)
            session.flush()
            return task.id
        return None
```

I instantiate BaseDB in main thread and call add_task function from different threads. After dozens of calls I get this error:

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError'>
(sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

So, unlike most other posts I don't have the problem with the path to the database file because my app adds a lot of rows in it. Maybe it is because DB is locked by other thread, but I use thread lock everywhere. Any ideas how to solve this problem?